# How do I know which one corresponds to what frequency, in `AnalyserNode`'s FFT analysis data?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

In *Web Audio API*, [`AnalyserNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode)'s [`getFloatFrequencyData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/getFloatFrequencyData) and [`getByteFrequencyData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/getByteFrequencyData) methods give us *FFT analysis data*, **whose domain is *frequency*** and codomain is *amplitude*, within **a typed array** that has [`AnalyserNode.frequencyBinCount`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/frequencyBinCount) elements, according to the *Mozilla Developer Network*.

How do I know which element is mapped to what frequency, as to the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The frequency domain output from an `AnalyserNode` is fairly simple.
Let the array have length N, and let f be the array.  Then f[0] is the
DC component and f[N-1] corresponds to component at a frequency of
context.sampleRate / 2.  The remaining points are equidistributed
between these values.

There are some additional complications due to how the analyser
works.  A window is applied to the signal before computing the
transform, and this results in a "smearing" of the frequency values,
so that a pure sine wave may not have a transform that is non-zero at
exactly one value.